# nano language set to French when using version from homebrew

Tags: macos, mac, language, homebrew, nano

I just updated from OS X El Capitan to macOS Sierra this weekend. Everything went smoothly, until I opened `nano` this morning. Its settings are now in French:

[image: nano in French]

I actually have 2 installations of `nano` on that computer: the default provided by macOS, and an additional version installed via `brew`. That's the one that seems to be in French right now.

`$ which nano
/usr/local/bin/nano`

If I switch back to the default installation of `nano`...

`$ brew unlink nano
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/nano/2.7.1... 44 symlinks removed
$ which nano
/usr/bin/nano`

My problems go away.

Why would homebrew's `nano` install be in French, and how can I set it to use English instead?

Thanks!

Comment: I realize it's a tiny detail; I wouldn't normally mind, but in this case it changes some of the keyboard shortcuts (I now have to type `o` to confirm when exiting instead of `y`), and it's really confusing for my muscle memory.

Comment: See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/658 and specifically https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/658#issuecomment-250991481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @EricAya in his comment above, I was able to solve the issue by setting `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in my shell startup script:

`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

That solved the issue. For more details, check [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/658).

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is adding "--disable-nls" to the recipe:

`brew edit nano`

Then change the configuration options:

```
system "./configure", "--disable-debug",
                      "--disable-nls", 
                      "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                      "--prefix=#{prefix}",
                      "--sysconfdir=#{etc}",
                      "--enable-color",
                      "--enable-extra",
                      "--enable-multibuffer",
                      "--enable-nanorc",
                      "--enable-utf8"
```

This will disable support for non-English ("Native Language Support") and only use English.